# Selecting a random element of array to set a Youtube videoId API

Tags: javascript, arrays, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to set up an array of videoId's to be able to choose from to be randomly loaded. I tried to add the videos array as a videoId, and it didn't work. I'm kind of a JS newb, so I'm not really sure what it is I should be passing back for this. I got as far as this:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
function rotateYT() {
    var videos = [
        'ZMnjkcvjN-E',
        'RFQfSMbLCWw',
    ];

    var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
}
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '300',
        width: '300',
        videoId: videos[index], //where I'm trying to get the random videos
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        }
    });
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    event.target.mute();
    event.target.setPlaybackQuality('small');
}
</script>
```

Comment: You never call the function, and the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: The variables `videos` and `index` are local to `rotateYT`, you can't use them in `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function needs to return the selected video ID:

```
function rotateYT() {
    var videos = [
        'ZMnjkcvjN-E',
        'RFQfSMbLCWw',
    ];

    var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
    return videos[index];
}
```

Then you need to call it in `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    var videoID = rotateYT();
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '300',
        width: '300',
        videoId: videoID,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh gosh.. as soon as you said it was local, I realized my dumb mistake :/. I just included the array in the function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady and called videos[index] and that worked. Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't repeat the array in two functions. Just do it as I showed, so you keep the information in one place.